# Getting CSP reports on www.pagespeed-mod.com

Tags: content-security-policy, mod-pagespeed

I have switched to using Content-Security-Policy for my website. I'm starting to see reports about the following not being allowed: https://www.pagespeed-mod.com/v1/taas

Does anyone know why the website is trying to load this file? I'm using Google Analytics and Tag Manager, but I don't think that I have any page speed mod installed. Maybe this is an extension in the user's browser? Or when they open developer tools? Another source I could think of is automatic optimization through Cloudflare which I'm also running on.

Extra info: The source of loading this script is https://3001.scriptcdn.net/code/static/1 which doesn't reveal much about who made that.

Answer (score 7):

Had the exactly the same issue and preventing me from using Element Inspector/ debugger. It appears to be some Chrome extension you have installed gone rogue, see if you have extension called "Auto Refresh Plus" installed like i did before.

Comment: I don't have that extension. I do have "Super Easy Auto Refresh" but I don't think that one is related to the error. But one of my visitors probably has the Auto Refresh Plus extension installed.

Comment: It does indeed come from "Auto Refresh Plus"
What caught my suspicion is that there's a check against a lot of pornsites, including some that sound quite interesting ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I also see reports on https://www.pagespeed-mod.com/v1/taas being blocked with the same source of loading. It seems to happen in short periods on the various resources I have reports from. This indicates that it is related to the user/browser and not related to the site itself.

The same can be seen with translators, extensions, security proxies etc. I have given up trying to attribute the source of anything that is likely not caused by legitimate site content.